# Jquery text method not displaying special character

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I have the following piece of code

```
<button type="button" onclick="SetApprove('{!myPA.P__c}'); jQuery('#approvePName').text('{!myPA.P__r.name}');  jQuery('#approvePType').text('{!myPA.P__r.P_Type__c}');  **jQuery('#approvePCT').text('{!myPA.Pub__r.Curr_Tar__c}');** jQuery(document.getElementById(pAIdForApprove)).val('{!myPA.Id}'); viewApproveForm();return false;">Approve</button>
```

//this part below is within a jquery popup div

```
<label for="checkbox">Yes I <b>Approve</b>
        <b id="approvePType">Dec</b> for submission to <b id="approvePCT">TBD</b>
```

Here what is happening is that `myPA.Pub__r.Curr_Tar__c` has special characters so the jquery popup div is not showing. can anyone tell me an alternative to the jquery text method?

Comment: Try `jQuery('#approvePCT').text('{!JSENCODE(myPA.Pub__r.Curr_Tar__c)}');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use visualforce `JSENCODE` function

```
jQuery('#approvePCT').text('{!JSENCODE(myPA.Pub__r.Curr_Tar__c)}');
```

[**JSENCODE**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)

> Encodes text and merge field values for use in JavaScript by inserting
>   escape characters, such as a backslash (), before unsafe JavaScript
>   characters, such as the apostrophe (').

**USE**

> {!JSENCODE(text)} and replace text with the merge field or text string
>   that contains the unsafe JavaScript characters.